# Not able to explode json string in hive

Tags: sql, arrays, json, hive, hiveql

```
[{"name":"john","id":12,"location":"delhi"},{"name":"raj","id":18,"location":"mumbai"},{"name":"Rahul","id":14,"location":"hyd"}]
```

I have this string(not struct) after using `get_json_object` on one record in the hive table. I need to explode this to create a new table with column names as name,id and location. Can someone help.

`Explode()` or `inline()` accepts array of struct. Tried `explode(Array(struct(my get_json_object output)))` but it does not give the expected result.

Comment: In the second and third object in your JSON, the key `name` is not properly enclosed in double quotes. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo while posting it here. Actual data does not have this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert string to array of JSON objects first: remove square brackets, split by comma between curly braces and explode. Then use json_tuple with lateral view to extract all values. See this demo:

```
with mytable as (--demo table, use your table instead
select '[{"name":"john","id":12,"location":"delhi"},{"name":"raj","id":18,"location":"mumbai"},{"name":"Rahul","id":14,"location":"hyd"}]' as json_string
)

select --t.json_string as original_string, --commented
      e.pos as position_in_array,
      --values from json
      x.name, x.id, x.location
      
  from mytable t 
      lateral view outer posexplode( split(regexp_replace(json_string,'^\\[|\\]$',''),      --remove []
                          '(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)'  --split by comma only after } and before {
                         )                    --converted to array of json strings
                               )e as pos, json --exploded array element with position
       --extract all from e.json 
      lateral view json_tuple(e.json,'name', 'id', 'location') x as name, id, location
```

Result:

```
position_in_array  x.name   x.id    x.location  
0                  john     12      delhi
1                  raj      18      mumbai
2                  Rahul    14      hyd
```